# how do I switch from mongoDB & Express to local state?

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, express, redux, react-redux

I'm following a `react redux` tutorial to build a `crud` app. But I don't want to use `mongoDB` or `express`.

How can I remove that and use the local state instead?

here is a link to the part of the video that I am in:
[CRUD with Redux #03. AJAX Request and ExpressJS Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZAlQDxDDas&list=PLuNEz8XtB51KfnHc99GwscPy1UbLJyXHW&index=3)

It’s giving me so many errors. I use `cloud9` IDE by the way if that helps. But like i said I want to use a local state instead of a database. I’ve followed the tutorial up to this point exactly.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You can make a folder named for example api where you make methods with `fetchAll()` etc which will return a `promise` resolving to the data you want to return.

You will have to make some files that return the data you want then though.

Example:

```
const DATEGROUPS = ['HOUR', 'DAY', 'WEEK', 'MONTH'];

exports.getAvailableDateGroups = async function getAvailableDateGroups() {
  return dategroups.map(x => ({ id: x, label: x }));
};
```